# Pretty print a 2D matrix in C (numpy style)

Tags: c, matrix, formatting

Works for any 2D matrix represented by a 1D array. Comments and criticism welcome. Also wondering whether the code can be made shorter. It's really messy right now.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef float fpoint_t; 

void print(fpoint_t* m, int row_size, int col_size)
{

    int i, j;
    printf(" array([");

    if(row_size == 1 || col_size == 1)
    {
        int len = row_size == 1? col_size : row_size;

        if(col_size == 1)
        {
            for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                if(i == len - 1)
                    printf("%.2e", m[i]);

                else
                {
                    if(m[i] >= 0) printf(" %5.2e, ", m[i]);
                    else printf("%5.2e, ", m[i]);
                    if((i + 1) % 6 == 0) 
                        printf("\n\t");
                }   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                if(i == 0)
                    printf(" %.2e\n", m[i]);
                else if(i == len - 1)
                    printf("\t %.2e", m[i]);

                else
                {
                    if(m[i] >= 0) printf("\t %5.2e,\n", m[i]);
                    else printf("\t %5.2e,\n", m[i]);
                }   
            }
        }

        printf(" ])\n");

        return;
    }

    if (row_size > 10)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            if(i == 0)
                printf("[ ");
            else
                printf("\t[ ");
            if(col_size > 10)
            {
                for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    if(j < 2)
                    {
                        if(m[i * col_size + j] >= 0) printf(" %5.4e,\t", m[i * col_size + j]);
                        else printf("%5.4e,\t", m[i * col_size + j]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(m[i * col_size + j] >= 0) printf(" %5.4e, ", m[i * col_size + j]);
                        else printf("%5.4e, ", m[i * col_size + j]);
                    }

                }

                printf("...,  ");

                if(m[i * col_size + col_size - 3] >= 0) 
                    printf(" %5.4e,\t\n\t", m[i * col_size + col_size - 3]);
                else 
                    printf("%5.4e,\t\n\t", m[i * col_size + col_size - 3]);

                if(m[i * col_size + col_size - 2] >= 0) 
                    printf("   %5.4e,\t", m[i * col_size + col_size - 2]);
                else 
                    printf("  %5.4e,\t", m[i * col_size + i]);

                if(m[i * col_size + col_size - 1] >= 0) 
                    printf(" %5.4e", m[i * col_size + col_size - 1]);
                else 
                    printf("%5.4e", m[i * col_size + col_size - 1]);
            }

            else
            {
                for(j = 0; j < col_size; j++)
                {
                    if(j != col_size - 1)
                        printf("%.6g, ", m[i * col_size + j]);
                    else 
                        printf("%.6g", m[i * col_size + j]);
                }
            }
            printf(" ],\n");
        }

        printf("\t...,\n");

        for(i = row_size - 3; i < row_size; i++)
        {
            printf("\t[ ");
            if(col_size > 10)
            {
                for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    if(j < 2)
                    {
                        if(m[i * col_size + j] >= 0) printf(" %5.4e,\t", m[i * col_size + j]);
                        else printf("%5.4e,\t", m[i * col_size + j]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(m[i * col_size + j] >= 0) printf(" %5.4e, ", m[i * col_size + j]);
                        else printf("%5.4e, ", m[i * col_size + j]);
                    }

                }

                printf("...,  ");

                if(m[i * col_size + col_size - 3] >= 0) 
                    printf(" %5.4e,\t\n\t", m[i * col_size + col_size - 3]);
                else 
                    printf("%5.4e,\t\n\t", m[i * col_size + col_size - 3]);

                if(m[i * col_size + col_size - 2] >= 0) 
                    printf("   %5.4e,\t", m[i * col_size + col_size - 2]);
                else 
                    printf("  %5.4e,\t", m[i * col_size + i]);

                if(m[i * col_size + col_size - 1] >= 0) 
                    printf(" %5.4e", m[i * col_size + col_size - 1]);
                else 
                    printf("%5.4e", m[i * col_size + col_size - 1]);
            }

            else
            {
                for(j = 0; j < col_size; j++)
                {
                    if(j != col_size - 1)
                        printf("%.6g, ", m[i * col_size + j]);
                    else 
                        printf("%.6g", m[i * col_size + j]);
                }
            }
            if(i == row_size - 1)
                printf(" ]])\n");
            else
                printf(" ],\n");
        }
    }

    else
    {
        for(i = 0; i < row_size; i++)
        {
            if(i == 0)
                printf("[ ");
            else
                printf("\t[ ");

            if(col_size > 10)
            {
                for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    if(j < 2)
                    {
                        if(m[i * col_size + j] >= 0) printf(" %5.4e,\t", m[i * col_size + j]);
                        else printf("%5.4e,\t", m[i * col_size + j]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(m[i * col_size + j] >= 0) printf(" %5.4e, ", m[i * col_size + j]);
                        else printf("%5.4e, ", m[i * col_size + j]);
                    }

                }

                printf("...,  ");

                if(m[i * col_size + col_size - 3] >= 0) 
                    printf(" %5.4e,\t\n", m[i * col_size + col_size - 3]);
                else 
                    printf("%5.4e,\t\n", m[i * col_size + col_size - 3]);

                if(m[i * col_size + col_size - 2] >= 0) 
                    printf("\t   %5.4e,\t", m[i * col_size + col_size - 2]);
                else 
                    printf("\t  %5.4e,\t", m[i * col_size + i]);

                if(m[i * col_size + col_size - 1] >= 0) 
                    printf(" %5.4e", m[i * col_size + col_size - 1]);
                else 
                    printf("%5.4e", m[i * col_size + col_size - 1]);
            }

            else
            {
                for(j = 0; j < col_size; j++)
                {
                    if(j != col_size - 1)
                        printf("%.6g, ", m[i * col_size + j]);
                    else 
                        printf("%.6g", m[i * col_size + j]);
                }
            }
            if(i == row_size - 1)
                printf(" ]])\n");

            else
                printf(" ],\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *lot* of code is repetitive with only slight changes in format.  Instead of ...

```
       for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if(j < 2)
                {
                    if(m[i * col_size + j] >= 0) printf(" %5.4e,\t", m[i * col_size + j]);
                    else printf("%5.4e,\t", m[i * col_size + j]);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(m[i * col_size + j] >= 0) printf(" %5.4e, ", m[i * col_size + j]);
                    else printf("%5.4e, ", m[i * col_size + j]);
                }

            }
```

... consider the following conditional values for `"%s"` which may reduce code's `printf()`s by 75% or more

```
       #define JLOOP 3
       for (j = 0; j < JLOOP; j++) {
         const char *pre = ""; // shown here for illustration, even though always ""
         const char *post = j < JLOOP - 1 ? ",\t" : "";
         //         v--- add space to use space for positive numbers
         printf("%s% 5.4e%s", pre, m[i*col_size + j], post);
       }
```

---

Now with the above change, rather than use `" %5.4e"` in many places, use a macro and string literal concatenation.  Certainly easier to adjust one format than many.

```
      #define FMT_M "% 5.4e"
      ...
         // Many places 
         // printf("%5.4e%s", ...);
         printf("%s" FMT_M "%s", pre, m[i*col_size + j], post);
```

---

Recommend to use `size_t` for array indexing than `int`.  `int` maybe insufficient with large arrays.  Certainly not for small programs - but good coding practice.

```
// void print(fpoint_t* m, int row_size, int col_size) {
void print(fpoint_t* m, size_t row_size, size_t col_size) {
```

---

Add `const`.  This allows for some compiler optimizations and lets the caller know `*m` is not changed.

```
// void print(fpoint_t* m, int row_size, int col_size) {
void print(const fpoint_t* m, int row_size, int col_size) {
```

---

`printf()` of a generic string is a problem should a `"%"` appear in it - maybe due to code maintenance or changes.  Consider 1 of the 2 alternates - which likely generate the same code on a good compiler.

```
// printf("\n\t");
printf("%s", "\n\t");
// or 
fputs("\n\t", stdout);
```

---

Minor.  Some compilers reserve `..._t` identifiers.  Consider non-_t names.

```
// typedef float fpoint_t;
typedef float fpoint_T;
```

---

A commented sample output would help to document coding goals